# Limiting atan2 to specific angle ranges

Tags: atan2

I want my Player sprite to rotate following the position of the mouse cursor.
I'm using atan2 to set up a 360 degree rotation action script for my Player sprite.

```
atan2(XMouse-XPlayer,YMouse-YPlayer) - 90
```

Using this, 90 degrees is straight up, 0 is direct right, 270 degrees is straight down. I need the Player sprite to sit on the Left side of the screen and only face the Right side of the screen when it rotates (meaning it can't look backwards).

I need to limit my angles to both conditions; less than 90 degrees OR greater than 270 degrees.

Ideally, I'd like to set 0 degrees to straight up, then I only have to set my conditions to Angles less than 180 degrees (one conditional rather than two).

Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use `min()` and `max()` (although you haven't said what language you're working in...)

Answer (score 0):

If you use radians, then the condition to check for is that `abs(theta) < PI/2` is always true. Here's an image from Wikipedia, just to show you what I mean. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to have 0 degrees straight up and clockwise movement from 0 to 360 degrees

use the formula:

f(x,y)=180-90*(1+sign(y))* (1-sign(x^2))-45*(2+sign(y))*sign(x)

```
    -180/pi()*sign(x*y)*atan((abs(y)-abs(x))/(abs(y)+abs(x)))
```