# How to limit the return angle from atan2() to [-pi/4,pi/4]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, atan2

I am using atan2() to find the angle between x,y values. I understand atan2 method returns a numeric value between –pi and pi. How do I map that value to [-pi/4, pi/4]. The question is related to this [Limiting atan2 to specific angle ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956292/limiting-atan2-to-specific-angle-ranges) but I couldn't understand it well.

```
if (a > pi/4):
  a -= 2 * pi/4
  return a
elif(a <= -pi/4):
  a += 2 * pi/4
return a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale the angle down, just divide it:

```
return a/4
```

If you want to limit it to a certain range, use `min` and `max`

```
return max(-pi/4, min(pi/4, a))
```